# Strip HTML style attributes in dijit.Editor (onPaste)

Tags: editor, filter, dojo, paste

Is there anyway to make the dijit.Editor strip HTML style="" attributes from pasted content?

If I copy text from another site, it copies it's font-size, color, etc and puts it into span tags. I would prefer to only strip styles when pasting.

I already have a tried-and-tested regex to replace the content, but I don't know how to hook it up with the dijit.Editor. I tried pushing a function to contentPreFilters but that doesn't get called when pasting text.

Answer (score 1):

Try [the dojox.editor.plugins.NormalizeStyle Plugin](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/editor/plugins/NormalizeStyle.html) by Jared Jurkiewicz. It allows for configuring either CSS style or normal attributes output.

Answer (score 0):

```
htmlEditor.editNode.innerText
```

does the trick for me.